# How to print factors of a number?

Tags: python, math

I have a question about multiples in python. Does anyone know how I can get the program to print multiples of a certain number? Like if I had them in put "10", it should print "1,10,2,5" or something along those lines
Thanks

Comment: Multiples? Or do you mean *factors* as in your example? (Except that factors usually are limited to *prime factors*, which would be 2 and 5.)

Comment: Yes, I did mean factors, sorry!

Comment: You may want to look at [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) at Wikipedia for a survey of the problem and the best algorithms for it. However, for a toy example like 10, the brute-force algorithm (optionally with the `sqrt` optimization) given by achampion is probably good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Very naively you can test every number up to n(10)

```
n = 10
results = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n % i == 0:
        results.append(i)
print(results)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
n = 10
print([x for x in range(1,n+1) if n % x == 0])
```

But in reality you only need to test up to the sqrt of n. Using a simple generator:

```
def divisor(n):
    a = 1
    l = n ** 0.5
    while a <= l:
        if n % a == 0:
            if a == n//a:
                yield a,
            else:
                yield a, n//a
        a += 1

print([x for a in divisor(10) for x in a])
print(sorted(x for a in divisor(10) for x in a))  # Sorted
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from math import sqrt

def factor(n):
    i = 2
    limit = sqrt(n)    
    while i <= limit:
      if n % i == 0:
        yield i
        n = n / i
        limit = sqrt(n)   
      else:
        i += 1
    if n > 1:
        yield n

def factorGenerator(n):
    d=defaultdict(int)
    for f in factor(n):
        d[f]+=1
    return [(e,d[e]) for e in sorted(d.keys())]

def divisorGen(n):
    factors = factorGenerator(n)
    nfactors = len(factors)
    f = [0] * nfactors
    while True:
        yield reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [factors[x][0]**f[x] for x in range(nfactors)], 1)
        i = 0
        while True:
            f[i] += 1
            if f[i] <= factors[i][1]:
                break
            f[i] = 0
            i += 1
            if i >= nfactors:
                return

print list(divisorGen(10))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 5, 10]
```